# Configure karma to fail test execution when skipped cases are found (xdescribe or xit)?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, karma-runner

When running unit tests with karma and jasmine (I'm using angular 6), in console it's printed how many tests were skipped. I would like to know, first, if it is possible to print in console which tests are being skipped, and second, I don't think it is possible but I have to know, if I can configure karma to fail the execution when they are found.

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.